# Call stored procedure in a Linq-to-Entities query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using EF 6 & Visual Studio 13 free community.

I am using database-first approach in my current project.

I created A SQL Server DB project and added it to my project to work with EF

I created tables & some stored procedures. After I added the db to my project it created a class `procedure_name_Result` and i need to use linq queries in my project but I don't know how to call it in the query, or if it will even recognize it as I can't see it in the uploaded db

**EDIT** Thanks to you both answers i was able to know how to probably call in a Linq query

```
var query = from X where Y 
            select new {
                         elemnt, 
                         var_inside_query = DB.procedure_name(@params) 
                       };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Northwind database as sample project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace EF_SP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new NorthwindEntities())
            {
                var results = context.GetSalesByCategory("Seafood", "1998");

                foreach (var result in results)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", result.ProductName, result.TotalPurchase);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key. . .");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```